# Como puedo poner un while con arraylist

Tags: arraylist, while

Como puedo agregar un `while`, lo que quiero hacer es pedirle al usuario cuantos libro quiere crear y repetirlo hasta que llegue al numero que se ingreso

```
n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuantos libros deseas crear"));

ArrayList<Libro>listalibros=new ArrayList<>();

while(listalibros=<n){
    System.out.println("Escriba el titulo del libro:");
    Titulo=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escriba el autor:");
    Autor=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escriba el numero de ejemplares:");
    NoEjem=teclado.nextInt();
    Libro libro = new Libro(Titulo,Autor,NoEjem);
}
```

Comment: Estás escribiendo mal el operado, escribistes "=<", cuando en realidad es "<=".

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que solo deberías de realizar el while mientras la variable "n" sea mayor a cero,
Seria lago así:

```
n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuantos libros deseas crear"));
 while(n>0){ 
    System.out.println("Escriba el titulo del libro:");
    Titulo=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escriba el autor:");
    Autor=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escriba el numero de ejemplares:");
    NoEjem=teclado.nextInt();
    Libro libro = new Libro(Titulo,Autor,NoEjem);
    n--;
 }
```

Comment: por que pediste el metodo haceralgo(); si no lo tengo

Comment: solo es para ejemplificar... Ahí puedes hacer lo que quieras

Answer (score 0):

Deberias probar:

```
n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuantos libros deseas crear"));
ArrayList <Libro> listalibros = new ArrayList<>();
    while(n>0){
    System.out.println("Escriba el titulo del libro:");
    Titulo=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escriba el autor:");
    Autor=teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Escriba el numero de ejemplares:");
    NoEjem=teclado.nextInt();
    Libro libro = new Libro(Titulo,Autor,NoEjem);
    listalibros.add(libro);
    n--;
}
```

Comment: no funciono el programa

Comment: Buenas. Supuse que lo que necesitabas era añadir a una lista la cantidad y los libros que te indicaban, si no es esto tines que ser mas claro con la que quieres lograr.